# How can I map a DynamoDB AttributeMap type to an interface?

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb

Say I have a typescript interface:

```
interface IPerson {
    id: string,
    name: string
}
```

And I run a table scan on a persons table in dynamo, what I want to be able to do is this:

```
const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

client.scan(params, (error, result) => {
    const people: IPerson[] = result.Items as IPerson[];
};
```

I am getting the error `Type 'AttributeMap[]' cannot be converted to type 'IPerson[]'`

Obviously they are different types, however the data structure is exactly the same. My question is how can I essentially cast the dynamo `AttributeMap` to my `IPerson` interface?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The right way to do this is by using the AWS DynamoDB SDK `unmarshall` method.

---

*JavaScript AWS SDK V3 (post December 2020)*

Use the `unmarshall` method from the `@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb` package.

[Docs Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.html#convert-dynamodb-record-into-javascript-object).

```
const { unmarshall } = require("@aws-sdk/util-dynamodb");

unmarshall(res.Item) as Type;
```

Side note: the AWS DynamoDB JavaScript SDK provides a [`DynamoDBDocumentClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_lib_dynamodb.html#aws-sdklib-dynamodb) which removes this whole problem and uses normal key value objects instead.

---

*The previous version of the JavaScript AWS SDK (pre December 2020)*

Use the [`AWS.DynamoDB.Converter`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/Converter.html#unmarshall-property):

```
// Cast the result items to a type.
const people: IPerson[] = result.Items?.map((item) => Converter.unmarshall(item) as IPerson);
```

Doc for `unmarshall()`:

> unmarshall(data, options) ⇒ map
>
> Convert a DynamoDB record into a JavaScript object.

Side note: the AWS DynamoDB JavaScript SDK provides a [`DynamoDBDocumentClient`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html) which removes this whole problem and uses normal key value objects instead.

Comment: Typo in code, I think it should be:

`const people: IPerson[] = result.Items?.map((item) => Converter.unmarshall(item) as IPerson);`

Comment: For the AWS SDK V3 the equivalent is: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/modules/_aws_sdk_util_dynamodb.html#convert-dynamodb-record-into-javascript-object

Comment: I don't see an advantage to use `unmarshall` or `Converter` as it could be simply done by casting the object, other than adding another layer of complexity that needs to be cast in the end. Just look closely at your answer, it casts the object anyway.
It could be done by: `object as Type` and/or `result.Items?.map((item) => item as IPerson)`

Comment: I tend to agree with @Willian here. When you use the DynamoDB client from aws-sdk, the returned object is already unmarshalled. The reason your solution works is because of the type casting `const people: IPerson[] ` which can be done without the unmarshalling.

Comment: @Willian  just casting didn't work for me, for example, it worked for strings but it didn't work for array of strings

Answer (score 3):

I've just solve it by casting to `unknown` first:

`const people: IPerson[] = result.Items as unknown as IPerson[];`

Answer (score 1):

Extend the IPerson interface with AttributeMap like so:

```
interface IPerson extends AttributeMap {
    id: string,
    name: string
}
```

Comment: If I use your solution, BenjaminPaul, I'm getting a new error: "Property 'name' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'AttributeValue'."

Comment: Only works if you don't state the Type of the client.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is no built-in serialization for `aws-sdk`.

What I've done so far is like below, it works fine:

```js
interface IPerson {
    id: string,
    name: string
}

// for single object
const person = result?.Item as IPerson;

// for arrays
const people = result?.Items?.map((item) => item as IPerson);
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem but was using `get` rather than `scan`. I solved this problem using a type guard a.k.a. type predicate. I am using v2 of the AWS SDK and I am using an object of type `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` to read from the DynamoDB table. I first tried to use unmarshall as suggested in [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68323218/5134722), but this resulted in an empty object. Seems like the client I was using was already unmarshalling the object for me.

In this case, the problem reduces to a standard one: you have an object of type `any` and you want to convert it some some type `IPerson`. A standard way to do this is to use a [type predicate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates). Something like this:

```
function isPerson(obj: any): obj is IPerson{
    if(!obj){
        return false
    }
    if(!isSimpleProperty(obj, "id") || !isString(obj.id)){
        return false
    }
    if(!isSimpleProperty(obj, "name") || !isString(obj.name)){
        return false
    }
    return true
}

function isString(obj: any){
    return (typeof obj === 'string' || obj instanceof String)
}

function isSimpleProperty(obj: any, property: PropertyKey){
    const desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, property)
    if(!!desc){
        return (!desc.get && !desc.set)
    }
    return false
}
```

Then you can use a filter method to get back all the items you want, of the correct type:

```
const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

client.scan(params, (error, result) => {
    const people: IPerson[] | undefined = result.Items?.filter(isPerson)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `aws-sdk` library does not provider a Generic interface for you to set the response type. So you can't do something like:

```
const person = await client.get<IPerson>(params).promise();
```

As others have mentioned, you can cast the type using something like:

```
const person = result?.Item as IPerson;
```

The risk with this is `result?.Item` may not be the type of `IPerson` and you are tricking Typescript into thinking it is.

Because of the schemaless nature of DynamoDB, the item in your DB could technically be of any shape so it might not include the `id` and `name` attributes you require. Therefore, it would be prudent to have some checks in place incase the data isn't as you expect.

One way to do that is to use a formatter that maps your dynamoDB object to your expected response:

```
const client = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

interface IPerson {
  id?: string,
  name?: string
}

const format = (data: DynamoDB.DocumentClient.AttributeMap): IPerson {
  return {
    id: data?.id,
    name: data?.name
  };
} 

const person = await client.get(params).promise();
      
const response = format(basket.Item); // maps DynamoDB.DocumentClient.AttributeMap => IPerson
```

`DynamoDB.DocumentClient.AttributeMap` is the response type of `client.get` but scan or other client methods might have a different response type. However, the same principle still stands of mapping the response of the client to the type you require.